# Parse to Firebase enhanced push notifications

Tags: python, ios, firebase, parse-platform, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm migrating Parse to Firebase and I'm having trouble with the enhanced push notification.

Parse data (iOS side) was like:

```
{"ast":
  {"alert": {
    {"body": "body_test",
     "title": "title_test",
     "description": "description",
     "endpoint-proposal": "https://.."
     "launch-image": "https://..."
  },
  "sound": "chime",
  ... 
}
```

Working with Firebase API the **ast** tag is the **['notification']['body']**.

If I send

```
['notification']['body'] = 'Hello'
```

It works perfectly and generate the following push:

```
{"ast":
  {"alert": "Hello"}
}...
```

So, here the problem, I need to send a dictionary in that tag (alert) and I cannot do that because firebase set the value as string.

Example in python:

```
alert = dict()
alert['title'] = 'title'
alert['description'] = 'description'
alert['endpoint-proposal'] = 'https://..'
alert['launch-image'] = 'https://..'

fcm_payload['notification']['body'] = alert 

send_push()
```

And in the iOS side I get:

```
[AnyHashable("gcm.message_id"): 0:123456789,
 AnyHashable("aps"): {
    alert = "{\"body\": \"body\",
              \"launch-image\": \"https://...\",
              \"endpoint-proposal\": \"https://...\",
              \"description\": \"description\",
              \"title\": \"title\"}";
}]
```

Always as string :S

Is there any way to send that alert as dict?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `notification` [`body`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support) parameter will always be treated by FCM as a `String`. It's just the behavior. What you'll have to do is make use of the [`data`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream-http-messages-json) payload and put in your custom key-value pairs:

> On iOS, if the message is sent via APNS, it represents the custom data fields. If it is sent via FCM connection server, it would be represented as key value dictionary in **AppDelegate application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:**.

More details can be seen in this [Receiving Messages in iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/receive) doc. I think for your case, you just have to use the `notification` and `data` parameters together in your payload.

Answer (score 0):

json.loads() should get you a dict.

Comment: Already tested it. No matter what, it always set the value as string.